# How to unzip and move files in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps

Problem: I get an email with a zip file. In that zip are two files. I want to extract one of those files and place it in a folder in ADL.

I've automated this before using logic apps but the zip and extra file is throwing a wrench in the gears here. So far I've managed to get a logic app going to download the zip into a blob container and another logic app to extract the files to another container. Don't know how to proceed from there. Should I be using data factory? I want this automated and to run every week every time I receive an email from a specific sender.

Comment: The key is choose the [Compression type] of your source file, this will unzip for your file. If you dont know how to do it, you can have a look of my answer, it has detail steps.

Comment: Hi, can you work it out now? Any update?

Comment: thanks for the guide but I'm still having trouble. Is there a way to download the zip from an email account using data factory? after unzipping I want to move one of the files to ADL and delete the other. I did this using the move template but I can't figure out how to give the file a unique name every time its moved.

Comment: You can try to use office 365 Connector. Use Office 365 as the source. And for the second requirement, you can use if condition activiry.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

I am sorry, dont notice your source is ADL, the below steps only need to change the source as ADL is ok. the key is select the Compression type of your source, it will unzip the file for you.

**Original Answer:**

1. Create a pipeline,

[image]

2.Create a activity.

[image]

3.After you create a copy data activity, you need to choose the source and the sink. From your description, you need to unzip a file in a storage container to another container. So, please follow these steps:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

And the sink is similar, also choose the azure storage blob and choose the same linked service. Select the container that you want to copy to.

4.Then let's Validate all. If there is no problem, we can publish them.

[image]

5. Now please trigger your pipeline:

[image]

6.After that, your zip file will successful unzip and copy to another container.:)